# How to install grub on a legacy pc?

Tags: grub2, bootloader

When I tried to install my pc ubuntu it errored end of the installation(executing grub-install/dev/sda failed). After that I tried to repair boot and it says LegacyWindows detected. The boot of your pc is an EFI mode... I tried to secure boot disable but its already disabled. How I can solve this ?

Comment: Hi and welcome. You have not given any info that could be used to help you. what version of Ubuntu?

Comment: 20.10 Version of Ubuntu

Answer (score -1):

I've found this article and I think it should help you

https://www.aioboot.com/en/grub-legacy/

Comment: Thanks! I'm gonna try it when I have some free time.